# Selenium see new page after submitting form

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Using Selenium for Python, I fill out a form and click the submit button using .click() . This works successfully as I receive email confirming the form submission but I want to now see the page that is returned after clicking the submit button.

How do I see the new page that is returned?

Answer (score 2):

you're able to see the markup by timing out for a few seconds and printing page source. Adding:

```
time.sleep(5)
print(driver.page_source)
```

after your submit line should accomplish this

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I think I was not giving the page enough time to load. This fixed the issue:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.url_changes(browser.current_url))
```